# How to include DTD in a XML document

Tags: c#, xml

How do I include DTD in a XML document.
Please provide me a sample.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the DOCTYPE declaration:
`<!DOCTYPE root-element SYSTEM "filename">`

http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_intro.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about programmatically adding it in code on an `XmlDocument` in C# then you might want to look at the [XmlDocument.CreateDocumentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createdocumenttype.aspx) Method.

If not, you might want to expand on what it is you are after exactly.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use the XML classes in the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace myself because they're much easier to work with. It's very easy to create a doctype object like this:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

// ...

XDocumentType docType = new XDocumentType("myDoctypeName", null, "myown.dtd", null);
```

You can then build an XML document by creating a root XElement and wrapping the root and doctype in an XDocument like so:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(docType, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

e.g. for using global variables across several files

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration SYSTEM "sample.dtd">
<myxml>
<node1>&testval;</node1>
</myxml>

sample.dtd:
<!ENTITY testval    "1" >